# Annotation proccessor configuration from a Gradle multi module build in IntelliJ 2019.3 seems not to work correctly

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a Gradle multi module project that uses the Mapstruct annotation processor for data type mapping across Java modules. The Gradle build works fine but when I import the project into IntellJ IDEA 2019.3 I get an unexpected annotation processor configuration.

The project structure looks like this

```
.
├── build.gradle
├── module1
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               └── io
│                   └── wangler
│                       └── mapstruct
│                           ├── ApplicationModule1.java
│                           ├── Person.java
│                           ├── PersonDTO.java
│                           └── PersonMapper.java
├── module2
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── generated
│           │   └── ch
│           │       └── silviowangler
│           │           └── mapstruct
│           │               └── CarMapperImpl.java
│           └── java
│               └── ch
│                   └── silviowangler
│                       └── mapstruct
│                           ├── ApplicationModule2.java
│                           ├── Car.java
│                           ├── CarDTO.java
│                           └── CarMapper.java
└── settings.gradle
```

and the `build.gradle` that registers the annotation processor for `module1` and `module2`.

```
subprojects { p ->

    apply plugin: 'java-library'
    apply plugin: 'groovy'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.3.1.Final'
        implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.3.1.Final'

        testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.8'

        testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    }
}
```

When I compile the project using `./gradlew compileJava` all works out fine and I get no compilation errors.

But when I run *Rebuild Project* withing IntelliJ I get a compilation error in `module1` since IntelliJ does not have an annotation processor registered for `module1`.

```
Error:(6, 35) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class PersonMapperImpl
  location: class io.wangler.mapstruct.ApplicationModule1
```

[image: Wrong Annotation processor configuration]

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a known IntelliJ issue? The source code for this example can be found at https://github.com/saw303/idea-annotation-processors

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue in IDEA 2019.3. Looks like a bug. 
It occurs only if two modules has the same set of annotation processors.

To solve the problem you need to add any library using annotationProcessor directive to one of modules. It does not have to be a real annotation processor. This one is working for me:

```
annotationProcessor "commons-io:commons-io:${commonsIoVersion}"
```

I have created a defect in JerBrains bugtracker: [IDEA-230337](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230337)

Comment: Here's a way to apply this helpful workaround in a "self-uniqifying way". This is helpful for applying it on a project with many modules (one of our projects has 50+ submodules). It creates a bogus annotation process entry this is ignored by Intellij, but provides the uniqueness workaround.  

    `annotationProcessor files('./uniqifier-to-workaround-IDEA-230337-${project.name}')`  


That can be set in each module build file or in the top level build script's subproject {} entry